# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "28.дек.2018"

Tags: java, java-8, locale, simpledateformat, date-parsing

Possible Java 8 bug while parsing dates using pattern with dot after short month (like dd MMM.yyyy) for several months (not all of them) in Russian locale:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "28 дек.2018"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

with code:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM.yyyy", locale);
Object date = simpleDateFormat.parse("28 дек.2018");
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Just an observation, your question title text is different from that of the text in code.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead us `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: This is weird. On my Java 1.8.0_131 your formatter formats Dec 28, 2018 into `28 дек.2018` but refuses to parse the same string back.

Answer (score 2):

In Russian locale `MMM` makes dot part of the 3 month letter abbreveriation. Because of that the dot must not be part of the `SimpleDateFormat` pattern. For example today we have `10 янв. 2019`:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", locale);
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date())); // 10 янв. 2019
```

And when parsing your date with `dd MMM yyyy` pattern it works:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy", locale);
Object date = simpleDateFormat.parse("28 дек. 2018");
System.out.println(date); // Fri Dec 28 00:00:00 GMT 2018
```

Comment: In addition to this, if I'd say if you are writing both ends (for example browser and server side), I'd recommend you just send it as numbers. Specifically as ISO-8601, so there can be no confusion.

Comment: @coladict yes, especially as localized number formats can *change* as being discussed in other Q&As, so locally formatted strings do not make a good data exchange format.